# Адаптивная верстка? Поведение элементов

Tags: css

```css
#header{
            background-color:#252323;
            margin: 0 auto 0;
            max-width: 1366px;
            height: 60px;
            }
            #header:before{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            content: "";
            }
            #one{
            width:40px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            float:left;
            margin-left: 205px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            }
            #two{
            width: 220px;
            height: 20px;
            float:right;
            background-color: green;
            margin-right: 195px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 480px){

            #one{
                margin-left: 1px;
            }

            #two{
            width: 10px;
            margin-right: 1px;
            }

        }
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="header">
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="two"></div>     
   </div>
                
</body>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Почему у блока one, при уменьшении экрана чётко зафиксировано 2 положения. А блок two при уменьшении экрана ездит как ему угодно Получается Left важнее чем right?

Answer (score 1):

Блок не помещается из-за `margin-right: 195px;` если удалить,будет перемещаться как вы задумали и блок с `float:left` не может быть правее, чем блок с `float:right`